# Yii2 hasMany custom condition

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have sql condidtion `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Prices WHERE aliasId = :aliasId order by id desc) p1 group by p1.currency` and I am trying to use it in hasMany statement.

```
   $q = $this->hasMany(Prices::className(), ['aliasId' => 'id']);
   $db = \Yii::$app->db;
   $query = $db
            ->createCommand('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Prices WHERE aliasId = :aliasId order by id desc) p1 group by p1.currency')
            ->bindValue(':aliasId', $this->id);
        $query->prepare(true);
        $q->sql = $query->getRawSql();
        return $q;
```

But `$this->id` is empty when hasMany calling. Is there any way to bind custom query and link array there?

UPDATE.
I know that the reason of `$this->id` is empty, because I'm using `Prices::find()>with('prices')` in my Controller, so Yii creates query for all prices list. `hasMany` just adds `addWhere('in', $key, $value)` in empty query from `$link` parameter, I'm trying to override his query, but I can't.

Comment: can you please provide more code, where is this code defined?

Comment: All this code is from getPrices function in PricesAlias ActiveRecordClass,(Prices class is empty Active Record). Shortly, I have many rows in Prices table with aliasId property(Which links PricesAlias and Prices tables). In method getPrices I need to return last Prices records with unique currency field.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you trying to achieve and which problem you actually have. Can you make this clearer? Please edit your post. And why do you have that nested query? AFAIK you don't need that. And you create a hasMany query $q that you later change with $q->sql? Does this all make sense at all? Sorry, mabe my fault...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`$this->id` is empty for new `PriceAlias` instances, and it's filled only after the model is saved in db - you are getting an empty value most likely because `getPrices()` is called before the model is saved in db.</strike>

You can test if `$this->id != null` or `$this->isNewRecord == false` before building the custom command, otherwise return `null`, an empty array or as required.

UPDATE 1: not sure I fully understand your update, 
`Prices::find()>with('prices')` does create a `WHERE ... IN (...)` query, but
`hasMany` does not add an `addWhere` rule, it creates a relation for the ActiveRecord class. In your case:

```
$this->hasMany(Prices::className(), ['aliasId' => 'id'])
// generates: SELECT * FROM `prices` WHERE `aliasId` = :id
```

And the query is executed only when you specifically call `getPrices()` for an object.

So your problem is? after `$q->sql = $query->getRawSql();` statement, `$q->sql` is not `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM Prices WHERE aliasId = :aliasId order by id desc) p1 group by p1.currency` ?

UPDATE 2: I understand now. I can't think of any way of using `Prices::find()->with()` on relations with custom sql, at least not as the one you would like to use.

I can only suggest to find an alternative to `find()->with()` in your controller if you need to keep the custom query.

Comment: I update my question, sorry for non-full information.

Comment: ActiveRelationTrait in Yii can generates one query for records list relation, in this case '::find()->with('prices')' for example. And when It's working in 'with' mode, I need to add aliasId list, which creates in ActiveRelationTrait::buildBuckets by YII, in my query.

Answer (score 0):

From official doc:

```
$subQuery = (new Query())->select('id')->from('user')->where('status=1');

// SELECT * FROM (SELECT `id` FROM `user` WHERE status=1) u 
$query->from(['u' => $subQuery]);
```

In your case it should be something like this:

```
$subQuery = (new Query())->select('*')->from('Prices')->where('aliasId = :aliasId', ['aliasId'=>$aliasId])->orderBy('id');
$query->from(['p1' => $subQuery])->groupBy('p1.currency');
```

Comment: I can't use $aliasId in my query, because ActiveRelation call getPrices only once for whole list when I'm trying to join table using ->with ActiveRecord method.